# Abrir Bootstrap Modal do code-behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, bootstrap-3, modal, visual-studio-2015

Preciso abrir um modal quando a senha ou usuário estiverem incorretos, ele vai ficar no **Else**  .. porém,não abre o modal

```
protected void bntLogar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Registrar criptografia = new Registrar();

        if (Login.logarUsuario(txtUser.Text, criptografia.CriptografiaMD5(txtSenha.Text)))
        {
            //Cria um cookie do lado do servidor
            HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("estado", "conectado");

            //Define a validade do cookie (10 dias a partir de hoje)
            cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(12);

            //Envia o cookie para o cliente
            Response.Cookies.Set(cookie);

            //Redireciona para a pagina inicial
            Response.Redirect("Admin.aspx");

            //fortawsome
        }
        else
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", "openModal();", true);
        }

    }
```

E coloquei dentro da tag  o código JavaScript

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function openModal() {
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
        }
    </script>
```

Código do modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalLogin" runat="server" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4>Warning</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Watch out! Your about to be locked out.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse código não funciona porque o ScriptRegister está a registar um script de Startup, ou seja quanto a pagina carrega pela primeira vez, como isso já passou o script nao é executado.
A alternativa seria usar:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", "openModal();", true);
```

Código para o Script manager

```
   <asp:ScriptManager runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
```

EDIT:

O ultimo problema é o jQuery estar a chamar o id errado no HTML está o modal assim:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalLogin" runat="server" role="dialog">
```

Note que o ID do modal é "modalLogin" logo todas as interações que serão feitas com o modal serão por esse ID.

No jquery o codigo está:

```
$('#myModal').modal('show');
```

Que essencialmente significa: Encontre o elemento HTML com o ID "myModal" e converta o para um modal com o argumento sendo o "show". Visto que o ID do modal é "modalLogin" e esta a chamar o ID "myModal" nada irá acontecer

Troque para:

```
$('#modalLogin').modal('show');
```

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno.
Testei o código mas não funcionou.. continua não aparecendo o modal quando não autentica o usuário.

Comment: A pagina .aspx (layout ou master) tem um ScriptManager associado?
Editei a resposta.

Comment: Verdade, faltava isso. Coloquei logos após `<form id="form1" runat="server">` mas não funcionou.

Coloquei o código do modal no post.. realmente não tenho ideia do por que não funciona

Comment: Editei a resposta de novo, suponho que seja esse o problema final.

Comment: Muito obrigado por sua atenção.. apliquei as correções necessárias mas mesmo assim não funciona.. nada do modal abrir.. realmente não sei o que esta ocorrendo.

Comment: O retire a tag "runat=server" do modal, isso muda o ID para um gerado automaticamente. Esperemos que seja a ultima coisa